# How to setup new git project on TFS using git bash

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-bash

I'm trying to learn git.

My git repository is on Visual Studio Team Services.
I code in visual studio.
I use git bash.

I'd like to use git by the command line (I like to understand what is happening).

First I created a new git project on TFS from the web browser. I did setup ssh so I could do commands from git bash. It works.

1. When you create a git project in TFS, does it do the git init --bare on the server for you, or do you need to do it yourself?
2. If this is not done when you create the server, how do I do the git init -- bare on the server.

What I'd like to do is fairly standard I think: setup a Master branch on the server, people clone locally on their computer, when ready merge and push.

Thanks

Comment: You're making your life harder than it need be. Just download and install windows version of git https://git-scm.com/download/win and play with things locally. You can push between two local repos. If you really want to push to a server, just create one on github and you can push and pull from there.

Comment: I want to have a centralized master version. More than one person is going to work on that project. I already have stuff on TFS so I don't have a big reason to go to github.

Also I want to learn the command line just so I understand. After that I'd probably use the GUI.

Comment: ok, I was focused n the "learn git" part to get you going asap with git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the repository has been initialized after you create it in VSTS/TFS, you just need to run "git clone ssh://xxxx@xxxx.visualstudio.com:22/_git/Repo" command from Git Bash after you configure the SSH correctly. And then you can commit and push changes.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Before I commit and push I guess that I also have to git init in my project folder first?

Comment: @masp123 If you cloned the repository to your local machine and then add your project to the local repo, then you don't need to git init. You just need commit the changes and then push then. But if you create your project folder first, and then you want to push it to VSTS repository, you will need to run git init in your project folder first, and then commit the changes, add VSTS repository as remote repository and then push then changes.